# RewriteCond for certain QUERY_STRING needed

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I need to secure a website via Apache rewrite rules. The website has different portals, but all run on the same web port, so I can't do this via firewall. The only difference between the portals is the string in the URL. Portal 1 is for public access, Portal 2 is only for certain IP addresses.

Now I need to come up with RewriteConds and RewriteRules that manage this. My idea is to use `RewriteCond expr` to match the IP address of the client and then `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}` to match the string in the URL. If the client has an IP address that is NOT among the list of the "expr", but tries to go to the URL that matches the string, it gets a return code 403 back.

The following strings should match EXACTLY.

`p=101
p=101:
p=WORD1
p=WORD2`

The URL looks like this:
`https://host.domain.com/website/f?p=portal`
where portal would be 101, 101:, WORD1 or WORD2.

Here's what I have so far, which works fine:

`RewriteCond expr "! -R 'a.b.c.d/32'"
RewriteCond expr "! -R 'a.b.c.e/32'"
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} p=(101\:?|WORD1|WORD2) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=403]`

But, this also matches p=1011, p=10111, p=WORD1A, p=WORD2A and so on.

I need help to create a regex that exactly matches the 4 strings listed above, but nothing else. I've been googling a lot and also found a couple of questions on this page, but whatever I tried, nothing worked.

Any help is greatly appreciated.